# No solvable subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ of finite index

Tags: group-theory

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170144/showing-that-a-congruence-subgroup-is-solvable) and was informed in the comments that $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ has no solvable subgroups of finite index. Two questions:

1. Is this claim true?
2. Why?

I suspect it has something to do with $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ containing the free group of rank $2$, but I haven't been able to turn that into an actual proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general principle is that if $G$ is a group, $H < G$ is a finite index subgroup, and $A$ is any other subgroup, then $A \cap H$ has finite index in $A$.

In particular, if $A$ is free of rank $2$, then $A \cap H$ is free of some rank $k \ge 2$, in which case $H$ contains a free subgroup of rank $k \ge 2$.

This is inconsistent with $H$ being solvable.